# Getting rid of explicit super

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'd like to implement something like this

```
def after(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        super().f(*args, **kwargs)
        f(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner


class A:
  def f(self):
    print ('hello')


class B(A):

  @after
  def f(self):
    print ('world')

b = B()
b.f()
```

that is I would like to get rid of explicit `super` in some of my classes and replace it with `@before` / `@after` decorator (maybe with parameters).

That is, in this example, I would like `hello world` to be printed.

the idea is to increase the readability of the code, as in some classes I often use multiple inheritance, so I often override methods and  often have to use `super()`.

I think I could use `inspect` to determine the class instance that calls the decorator (although not sure about performance if I have many class instances).

is there a way to do this without sacrificing performance?

Comment: What's wrong about calling `super()`? How does using a decorator like this improve the situation?

Comment: the idea is to increase the readability of the code. I have to write something like `super().some_method(*args, **kwargs)` quite often. that is, I would not want to repeat myself specifying the method and arguments (in the `super()` line)  which python could get somehow automatically.

Comment: Using ```super()``` is far more readable than creating new wrappers which no one but you uses.

Comment: @me2beats Only that this will *decrease* the readability of the code. 1) It's less explicit. 2) It obfuscates the order of execution, since actual *content* of that very function has now been moved outside of it, in form of a decorator. So if you want to know what's going on you'll have to jump back and forth between body and decorators to see what that function is supposed to do. Decorators are meant to augment functions, not swallow part of their content. And 3) it doesn't save anything in terms of lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your decorator work, you just need it to make it a descriptor class, rather than a function. You need to implement the `__set_name__` method to get a reference to the class you've been added to. With the class reference, you can make a two-argument `super` call:

```
import functools

class after:
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.owner = owner
        self.name = name                 # using self.method.__name__ might be better?

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return functools.partial(self, instance)

    def __call__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        assert(self.owner is not None and self.name is not None)
        getattr(super(self.owner, instance), self.name)(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.method(instance, *args, **kwargs)
```

You could do a `before` too, which would be nearly the same, just with the last two lines in the reverse order (and some fiddling to handle the return value).

I'd note that this decorator is quite a bit less generally useful than calling `super` the normal way since you can't usefully interact with the value returned by the overridden method, or change the arguments being passed in to it. There's no `before` or `after` decorated method that can replicate these classes:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class Bar(Foo):
    def foo(self, x, y, z):
        return super().foo(x//2, y+1) * z
```

Comment: cool! just please correct the typo `ower`. Yes, this is not a universal approach, I'd also add that sometimes calling `super` for different class may be useful, or sometimes you may want both `before` and `after`. But these two decorators seem sufficient for most of my needs. Thanks!